# How can I label both coordinates in mmQGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, labeling, coordinates

How can I label both coordinates in mmQGIS? Everything I try leads to only one of the 2 coordinates (lat or lon) to be labeled. I cannot get both labeled at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need MMQGIS for this.  If you are using QGIS 1.8 then go to the advanced labeling options (Layer->Labeling)/  In QGIS 1.9 it will be in the layer Properties labeling tab.  Click the button with three dots next to the drop-down menu for "Label this layer with" (In QGIS 1.9 the button is labeled 'E...').  This opens an expression based label window.  Now type the following in the Expression box:

```
$x||','||$y
```

Alternatively you could make a field that contains both coordinates and then continue with MMQGIS.

Comment: Inserting some blanks around the comma will improve readability. You can even add a line break to get the coordinates in two lines.

Comment: Or put an 'E' and an 'N' at the start of each relevant coordinate (or Lat Lon depending on your CRS) - lots of options for beautiful labeling!

Comment: Very kind of you to take your time answering. The method proposed does not work with a grid generated by mmqgis. It does exactly the same as mmqgis does, namely lable only one coordinate at a time. I guess, now I have to find out how to generate a grid without mmqgis and then use your method.

Comment: I am sorry that I was misguided in trying to use mmqgis, I found out how to make a grid and lable it usrig the print composer, but now I have the problem that open layer plugins always change the units from degrees to something smaller (meters perhaps). How can I get back to degrees?