# Display M-values in a MultiPointM from a PostGIS database as a label in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, labeling

I have *MultiPointM*s in a PostGIS (v. 2.2.2) database.

I would like to know if it is possible in QGIS (v. 2.14.1) **to label each point with its M-Value**.

For instance:

> MultiPointM(1 1 0, 2 2 1, 3 3 2);
> *Coordinates obviously made up*

And in QGIS **I would like to have the point (1 1) to have a label with "0"**.
The point(2 2) would be labeled "1" and the point (3 3) would be labeled "2".

I would prefer having a **script-free solution** (as the final user is not myself).

> A friend suggested this : [How can I label both coordinates in mmQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70367/how-can-i-label-both-coordinates-in-mmqgis)
>
> Which gives some hints on the direction to go... The $x and $y work
> perfectly... But it doesn't seem to like $m (and I wouldn't know where
> to search for to know what would be the equivalent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually in the label expression editor under Geometry (I had to look it up ;)). To show the M value, you'd do this:

```
 m($geometry)
```

You can also use an arbitrary geometry definition as given in the example.

Comment: Thanks! This worked out well to get the M value, but I still have issues labeling each point of the multipoint individually...

Comment: Oh, right... I'll look into that when I have a chance. If nothing else, you can create a view on the table that uses ST_DumpPoints to provide a row for each point. That way your user will never have to update anything.